# 3-month moving average with missing periods

Tags: reporting

I am trying to track the 3 month moving average sales cycle length, using [this guide](https://salesforcesaint.com/2012/11/the-magic-of-a-moving-average-report/) as a starting point. The formula I'm using is:

> `(AGE:SUM+PREVGROUPVAL(AGE:SUM,CLOSE_DATE)+PREVGROUPVAL(AGE:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 2))/(RowCount+PREVGROUPVAL(RowCount, CLOSE_DATE)+PREVGROUPVAL(RowCount, CLOSE_DATE, 2))`

This works well if we have consistent deals being closed every month, but the issue is our pipeline at this moment is not big enough/can be spiky so that if we start segmenting by Channel, there are months where we do not have any records:[image: redacted report screenshot]

In this case, I've filtered to Q4 2023. We have closed opportunities in October and December, but not November. So the formula throws an error and doesn't calculate because `PREVGROUPVAL(AGE:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 2)` and `PREVGROUPVAL(RowCount, CLOSE_DATE, 2)` do not exist.

But there is a further issue: even if we had records from previous months (say September was included), this formula would still fail if there was no data for November. December's 3 month moving average would be calculated using December, October, and September. This of course is clearly not correct.

I've been trying to think about how to detect that November does not exist in this report, but have not figured out anything yet.

Comment: You can't report on data that is not there. What if you made fake 0$ Opportunities for each month then you would have at least a record to show up that meets the criteria and would fill in the grouping with at least a 0 in it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This could work but I see at least two possible issues.


1. This could cause confusion/annoyance among the sales team. Maybe there is some way of automatically creating and hiding these records?


2. Depending on what fake record I create, this could (very slightly) throw off the calculated average. My leadership is such that something like this might make them distrust the report entirely. I will need to think through what exactly the fake record could contain so that this report remains accurate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Read up on exponential smoothing and/or weighted moving average.

Comment: @identigral thanks will do. Could you explain a little how this would help in this situation?

Comment: You could hide them for list views or whatever but the user running the report would have to be able to read the record in order for it to show up on the report in the first place. If it helps your leadership out maybe fake is the wrong word and you use 'placeholder' because essentially that's what it is, a placeholder so that the month shows on the report regardless if there are 'real' opps showing their amounts. 

I don't know data reporting enough that you could detect it in Tableau or whatever. But with SF reports the data is there or it's not.